# named pipe windows behaves

Tags: c, windows, named-pipes

I'm trying to create a basic server with a named pipe in windows. The problem occurs when trying to connect the pipes(I suspect).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main(){
    HANDLE p1, p2;
    printf("Server...");
    p1 = CreateNamedPipe(TEXT("\\\\.\\PIPE\\pipe1"),PIPE_ACCESS_INBOUND,PIPE_TYPE_BYTE|PIPE_WAIT,3,0,0,0,NULL);
    p2 = CreateNamedPipe(TEXT("\\\\.\\PIPE\\pipe2"),PIPE_ACCESS_OUTBOUND,PIPE_TYPE_BYTE|PIPE_WAIT,3,0,0,0,NULL);
    if(p1 == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE || p2 ==  INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE ) { printf("pipe fail");exit(2);}
    printf("1. Pipes created");
    ConnectNamedPipe(p1,NULL);
    ConnectNamedPipe(p2,NULL);
    printf("2. Pipes connected");


    DisconnectNamedPipe(p1);
    DisconnectNamedPipe(p2);
    CloseHandle(p1);
    CloseHandle(p2);
    printf("3. Pipes disconnected & closed");

    printf("exit server...");

    return 0;
```

}

When running the program, it doesn't print anything and when i manually stop it it just prints 
`Server...1. Pipes created` (in my IDE console - Eclipse) or if I run program directly it, it prints the same then it holds.

Comment: ConnectNamesPipe: "Enables a named pipe server process **to wait for a client process to connect** to an instance of a named pipe". Do you have an independant process trying to connect to that pipe?

Comment: i was trying to see if it works.... so the standby is caused by the waiting for a client to connect to it?

Comment: It's not printing anything because you don't flush the buffers. Output to `stdout` is buffered and printing doesn't happen until you either explicitly flush the buffer or print a newline. Easiest solution is to add a `'\n'` to string in your `printf` calls.

Comment: Output to stdout is not buffered when it is not redirected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It takes two to tango here.  You'll need to write another program that calls CreateFile() to open the named pipe.  Only then will the ConnectNamedPipe() call in your server program complete.  Avoid using two pipes in your test program, pipes are bi-directional so you only need a single pipe to talk back-and-forth.  If you want to support multiple clients then simply call ConnectNamedPipe again after a pipe connection was established.  At which point it also becomes important to use overlapped I/O or threads.

Do take a look at the sample code included in the [MSDN articles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365799%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for named pipes.  It shows you how to write both the server and client code.

Comment: thank, and sorry for the beginners question but i missunderstood something.